# Deploying Oracle ADW Changes from development environment to production

Tags: oracle, schema, schema-migration, continuous-integration

I'm currently running an Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse (Oracle's cloud-based database offering) on version 19c. I have a development database on the Always Free Tier and my production database is a paid instance (with backups etc). I will likely also be making a staging instance soon.

When making changes to the database schema we have been making changes to my database schema as follows:

1. Change schema on the development environment using SQL statements (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, etc)
2. Test the development environment manually
3. Change the schema on the production environment using identical SQL statements
4. Test the production environment to make sure nothing is broken

I am aware that this is not the way it should be done, we need to implement some CI/CD to streamline these changes but we've only recently come out of our piloting phase where it was a rush to get the product working etc, I'm very keen to firm up our new systems.

How I'm imagining it'd go (changes in bold):

1. Change schema on the development environment using SQL statements (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, etc)
2. Test the development environment **with automated tests**
3. **Apply some tool to apply the same changes to my production system**
4. Test the production environment to make sure nothing is broken

I have seen that tools exist for other SQL database tools, such as MySQL, PostgreSQL etc but from my searches on Oracle-specific tools, I'm not sure if where to find a tool that can propagate the schema changes from our development database to a production database.

If you know of any tools that I can look at to do this functionality then I'd appreciate a pointer on where to look!

I'm aware this is similar to other questions, the ones I've looked at are:

- [Altering db schema in production environment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61688/altering-db-schema-in-production-environment)
- [Upgrade production database during software development lifecycle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28478/upgrade-production-database-during-software-development-lifecycle)

Both of these questions were asked several years ago and so I'm not sure if new things have come up recently.

Comment: Do not assume people know what ADW is.  Please add a description of it (Oracle's Cloud offering) and which version of the database you are using.  Also add if you are using the Free Tier.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll change that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Key Infrastructure Pieces

- Code Repository/Version Control System
- Separate (and licensed) Dev/Test/Prod environments

You seem to be missing the Test environment.

## Test Environment

I highly recommend using a Test environment.  One advantage is: You can use the actual Schema's name irregardless of environment.

One way to use the Test environment:

- Clone Prod to Test

  - usually a [clone of a pluggable database](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/pdb/pdb_clone/pdb_clone.html)
- apply Change scripts
- perform Unit Tests

## Automatic Test Scripts

There is a PL/SQL based Unit Testing package on GitHub ( [utPLSQL](https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL) ).

But, if you want an Oracle product, SQL Developer has [Unit Testing](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/04/unit-testing-your-plsql-with-oracle-sql-developer/) capabilities.

You'll most likely need to create the scripts that interface with your automation software.

## Automatic Schema Changes

Your second link mentioned LiquiBase.  This is now integrated into SQL Developer. Demo for Dev Schema to Prod Schema is available [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2020/02/5-minutes-demo-using-liquibase-in-sqlcl-to-version-oracle-database/).

You will use the new command line interface (SQLcl) for automation, not SQL Plus.

Another alternative (for new tables) is the SQL Developer [Cart feature](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/introducing-the-sql-developer-shopping-cart/). It can also work well for creating the `INSERT` scripts for the small Dimension Tables.

## Code Review

One thing you may want to incorporate into your process is a way to automate parts of the Code Review process.  I believe the key words to search in Google/Bing are "code sniffer".

SQL Developer has a [custom highlighting feature](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/05/version-19-1-and-custom-highlighting-dbms_output/) that I use to detect "bad code".

Example

- `TO_DATE()` without a format.
- `commit` inside of a `loop`.
- `when others then null` ( [other forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/15378931#15378931) ).

The review process is manual for me.  But, the custom highlighting helps the human code reviewer.

## TL;DR

You need to look at SQL Developer's set of features.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Michael - this is fantastic and just what we need. One extra question, will this also version items ORDS modules, handlers etc?

Comment: @AshOldershaw - I don't know.  That would be a good question for the Project Manager ( ThatJeffSmith ).  You can check his web site to see if he has mentioned such a feature.